# How to watch react-native node_modules changes

Tags: javascript, react-native, watchman, react-native-cli

When I run `react-native start` or `npm start` the packager starts and prompts to be `Looking for JS files in /Users/map/repos/myrepo/`

I've got Hot reloading enabled. When I change a file located within `/Users/map/repos/myrepo/node_modules/react-native/` seems to detect the change, however if I edit a file in a third party repository like `/Users/map/repos/myrepo/node_modules/react-native-menu/` looks like watchman is not detecting the change.

I've just upgraded React Native in my project to 0.39 and I think this wasn't the default behavior before. I've set up some logging in `react-packager/src/node-haste/index.js` and seems `react-native-menu` files are included in `hasteFSFiles`, however `change` event is not triggered.

I've tried deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling it, Cleaning Watchman state and other without luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, Looks like they redid React Native packager in version 0.39, although this bug is still present in v0.40. Until there is an official fix, if you want to detect changes of a library within `node_modules` you need to edit `node_modules/react-native/packager/defaults.js` and add your project name to `providesNodeModules`, like this:

`exports.providesModuleNodeModules = [
  'react-native',
  'react-native-windows',
  'react-native-menu',
];`

The issue where this has been reported can be found here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11301

Comment: maybe it was working recently, unfortunately not anymore

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to start react native packager with additional arguments

`npm run start -- --providesModuleNodeModules react-native,{any_node_module}`

Works with RN v0.42.0 for me

Comment: I get "unknown option '--providesModuleNodeModules' with this command.

Comment: @LukeWilliams your version of react native? Just checked v44 and it works

Comment: Different start script?  Mine generates this in RN 44

> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start "--providesModuleNodeModules" "react-native"